# question about jquery scrolltop

Tags: jquery, scroll

I scroll down a page using jQuery. For example, With the code below, the page scroll down to a div id "bottom" by clicking a link. It works fine, but the url in the address bar remains same. I want that when I click the link, it scroll down as it does, but also add # (or whatever is the url of the link below) in the address bar of the browser. 
For example, the url of page is `example.com/test.php`, it should become something like `example.com/test.php#`
Is it possible to do so? Thanks.

```
<a href="#" class="scrollToBottom">Scroll to bottom</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('a.scrollToBottom').click(function(){
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#bottom').offset().top }, 'slow');
                return false;       
        });
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the return false line.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a.scrollToBottom').click(function(){
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#bottom').offset().top }, 'slow');
        });
    })
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that already but if i remove that, the page behaves little strange. After scrolling down, it kind of refreshes the page. Is it because of animate or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `return false` from your code it will work as you want.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('a.scrollToBottom').click(function(){
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#bottom').offset().top }, 'slow');
        });
    })
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that already but if i remove that, the page behaves little strange. After scrolling down, it kind of refreshes the page. Is it because of animate or something else?

Comment: Its because the the anchor tries to redirect to the url set in its href property which is just a `#` here so the it remains on the same page but it will scroll to the top of the page. I dont understand why do you need `#` in the url after scrolling.

Comment: i need it cos # is not the only thing, it contains an ID as well, eg. #11, and i need that ID to post. can you recommend some alternative solution? Thanks

Comment: You can grab the href property from anchor while posting? Why do you need it in the address bar though

Comment: no i dont need animation. i just need to scroll down smoothly. Actually im using wordpress theme `wp_list_comments` generates the comments links and the form posts it. I am looking for some way which will let me to click a link having a specific css class and scroll to a div on same page.

Comment: Take a look at `jQuery` `scrollTo` plugin http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo